# React - focus input without the ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some inputs build with `Ant Design` library in the project that I jumped into few minutes away.

Usually, if I want to focus an input, I attach ref to it and I can do it this way. The input components are made in a way that I do not see a fast way to restructure it but need to focus another input when e.g. clicking on a button.

I've tried selecting it with just simple but it did not work:

```
const id = 'my_input';
const element = document.getElementById(id);
element.focus();
```

I've also tried quickly attaching refs to a `window.availableRefs` object that I created and then calling `focus()` on that ref (even on after `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`) but it does not work neither:

```
<Input ref={(el) => window.availableRefs[id] = el} />
```

Is there a way I can focus an input without the `refs`?
Link to the `Input` component from the UI library I have: [click](https://ant.design/components/input/)

Comment: well that is not valid javascript code. I am sure the console is throwing an error on `const element.focus();`

Comment: Sorry, of course it ja without the `const`. Was quickly rewriting this.

Comment: So does `getElementById` find the element? Are you selecting it before it exists on the page? Is there more than one element with the `id`?

Comment: yes, it finds the element.There is just one element like this on the page as I've also tried with `document.querySelectorAll`

Comment: If you go to the link I provided and try to write in the console `const element = document.querySelector('#components-input-demo-basic input')` and the focus this element, it does not work

Comment: weird. No clue what is going on with that. .select() and .value work

Comment: That's what I also noticed :(